# How to display different number of posts

Tags: posts, loop, pagination

How do I display different number of posts on the home page and archive pages, the archive pages can use the value set in the admin, but I want a custom number of posts to be displayed on the home page with pagination. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a very short plugin.

```
function posts_on_home_page( $posts_per_page ) {
    if ( is_home() )
        return 5;
    return $posts_per_page;
}

add_filter( 'pre_option_posts_per_page', 'posts_on_home_page' );
```

This is actually pretty close to the Codex example for [`pre_option_(option_name)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_option_(option_name)).

Comment: But is there a way to distinguish home.com from home.com/page/2/